# Superset dashboard -Write back to DB

Tags: database, charts, dashboard, apache-superset

I am pretty new to superset dashboards and I have a requirement in chart where  user can enter comments in a text box and write back the comments  to database table ? Is this feature can be achieved in superset ,Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, this feature is not supported in Apache Superset.  The closest approximation would be embedding a form of some sort via an iFrame in your dashboard, then having that write to your database.